# how to make fibonacci stop by last input number in php

Tags: php, loops, fibonacci

I have this input and output:

Input : 3 
Output : 1 1 2 3 
Input : 5 
Output : 1 1 2 3 5 
Input : 12 
Output : 1 1 2 3 5 8 
Input : 25 
Output : 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21

I have tried summing up using this code:

```
<?php
  function fibonaci($total)
        {
            $previousNum=1;
            $numbersNow=1;

            $valueOutput = "$previousNum $numbersNow";

            for ($i=1; $i<$total; $i++)
            {
              $output = $numbersNow + $previousNum;
              $valueOutput = $valueOutput . " $output";

              $previousNum = $numbersNow;
              $numbersNow = $output;
            }
            return $valueOutput;
        }

        echo fibonaci(3);
        echo "<br>";

        echo fibonaci(5);
        echo "<br>";

        echo fibonaci(12);
        echo "<br>";

        echo fibonaci(25);
        echo "<br>";
?>
```

Which outputs: 
1 1 2 3 
1 1 2 3 5 8 
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393

Comment: You have not define total in for ($i=1; $i<$total; $i++), shouldnt it be output?

Comment: @Grumpy `$total` is argument of function.

Comment: Your `for` loop condition needs to compare the number to output and `$total`, at the moment it's outputting `$total` iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your code as:

```
function fibonaci($total)
{
    $previousNum=1;
    $numbersNow=1;

    $valueOutput = "$previousNum $numbersNow";

    while (true)
    {
      $output = $numbersNow + $previousNum;

      // break the loop if next number is greater than $total
      if ($output > $total) {
          break;
      }

      $valueOutput = $valueOutput . " $output";

      $previousNum = $numbersNow;
      $numbersNow = $output;
    }
    return $valueOutput;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/auq3G).